# A word that means "fit"

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose for example a team of people are using a single email address to share files among one another (each person has the username and password of that email address). There is another service that allow each person to have their own credentials and be able to access the documents by granting permissions to each user. This service would better suit their needs. We would say that this service is more _____ than email.

Comment: I'll start with the obvious one: suitable?

Comment: I go with suitable over appropriate.  While the word fits there is just something off about its use here.  I don't know what.  Here's one for suitable.  I might add that the package may better serve needs but be inappropriate for some other reason.

Comment: If @Akshay's *appropriate* is too much to type, you could always just use ***apt***.

Comment: I will go with "adapted".

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fit ... Or any other thesaurus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Appropriate** is the word you're looking for.

Comment: Can you quote the relevant definition of your suggested word from a dictionary, please? Be sure to mention which dictionary, and add a hyperlink back to where you found it. Thanks!